# Write config in Zend Framework with APPLICATION_PATH

Tags: zend-framework, config

For an application I'd like to create some kind of setup-steps. In one of the steps the database configuration is written to the application.ini file. This all works, but something very strange happens: All the paths to the directories (library, layout, ...) are changed from paths with APPLICATION_PATH . to full paths. As you can imagine, this isn't very systemfriendly. Any idea how I can prevent that?

I update the application.ini with this code:

```
# read existing configuration
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(
    $location,
    null,
    array('skipExtends'        => true,
    'allowModifications' => true));

# add new values
$config->production->doctrine->connection = array();
$config->production->doctrine->connection->host = $data['server'];
$config->production->doctrine->connection->user = $data['username'];
$config->production->doctrine->connection->password = $data['password'];
$config->production->doctrine->connection->database = $data['database'];                

# write new configuration
$writer = new Zend_Config_Writer_Ini(
    array(
        'config'   => $config,
    'filename' => $location));
$writer->write();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Zend_Config_Ini uses the default ini scanning mode (INI_SCANNER_NORMAL), it will parse all options and replace constants with their respective values. What you could do, is call [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) directly, using the INI_SCANNER_RAW mode, so the options aren't parsed.

ie. use

```
$config = parse_ini_file('/path/to/your.ini', TRUE, INI_SCANNER_RAW);
```

You will get an associative array that you can manipulate as you see fit, and afterwards you can write that back with the following snippet (from the comments):

```
function write_ini_file($assoc_arr, $path, $has_sections=FALSE) { 
    $content = ""; 
    if ($has_sections) { 
        foreach ($assoc_arr as $key=>$elem) { 
            $content .= "[".$key."]\n"; 
            foreach ($elem as $key2=>$elem2) { 
                if(is_array($elem2)) 
                { 
                    for($i=0;$i<count($elem2);$i++) 
                    { 
                        $content .= $key2."[] = ".$elem2[$i]."\n"; 
                    } 
                } 
                else if($elem2=="") $content .= $key2." = \n"; 
                else $content .= $key2." = ".$elem2."\n"; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    else { 
        foreach ($assoc_arr as $key=>$elem) { 
            if(is_array($elem)) 
            { 
                for($i=0;$i<count($elem);$i++) 
                { 
                    $content .= $key2."[] = ".$elem[$i]."\n"; 
                } 
            } 
            else if($elem=="") $content .= $key2." = \n"; 
            else $content .= $key2." = ".$elem."\n"; 
        } 
    } 

    if (!$handle = fopen($path, 'w')) { 
        return false; 
    } 
    if (!fwrite($handle, $content)) { 
        return false; 
    } 
    fclose($handle); 
    return true; 
}
```

ie. call it with :

```
write_ini_file($config, '/path/to/your.ini', TRUE);
```

after manipulating the $config array. Just make sure you add double quotes to the option values where needed...

Or alternatively - instead of using that function - you could try writing it back using Zend_Config_Writer_Ini, after converting the array back to a Zend_Config object, I guess that should work as well...

Comment: BTW This is of course assuming you're using PHP 5.3 or later (since the INI_SCANNER_RAW mode doesn't exist in prior versions of PHP).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guess you could iterate over the values, checking for a match between the *value* of `APPLICATION_PATH`, and replacing it with string *literal* `APPLICATION_PATH`.

That is if you know that `APPLICATION_PATH` contains the string `'/home/david/apps/myapp/application'` and you find a config value `'/home/david/apps/myapp/application/views/helpers'`, then you do some kind of replacement of the leading string `'/home/david/apps/myapp/application'` with the string `'APPLICATION_PATH'`, ending up with `'APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"'`.

Kind of a kludge, but something like that might work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot - but have you tried running your `Zend_Config_Writer_Ini` code while the `APPLICATION_PATH` constant is **not** defined? It should interpret it as the literal string 'APPLICATION_PATH' and could possibly work.